# Call function in pyspark with values from dataframe as strings

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have to call a function `func_test(spark,a,b)` which accepts two string values and create a df out of it. `spark` is a `SparkSession` variable
These two string values are two columns of another dataframe and would be different for different rows of that dataframe.

I am unable to achieve this.

Things tried so far:
1.

```
ctry_df = func_test(spark, df.select("CTRY").first()["CTRY"],df.select("CITY").first()["CITY"])
```

Gives CTRY and CITY of only the first record of the df.

2.

```
ctry_df = func_test(spark, df['CTRY'],df['CITY'])
```

Gives `Column<b'CTRY'>` and `Column<b'CITY'>` as values.

Example:
df is:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
|     CTRY |     CITY |    XYZ    |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|      US  |     LA   |      HELLO|                                    
|      UK  |     LN   |      WORLD|
|      SN  |     SN   |      SPARK|
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

So, I want first call to fetch `func_test(spark,US,LA)`; second call to go `func_test(spark,UK,LN)`; third call to be `func_test(spark,SN,SN)` and so on.

```
Pyspark - 3.7
Spark - 2.2
```

Edit 1:

Issue in detail:

`func_test(spark,string1,string2)` is a function which accepts two string values. Inside this function is a set of various dataframe operations done. For example:- First spark sql in the func_test is a normal select and these two variables string1 and string2 are used in the where clause. The result of this spark sql which generates a df is a temp table of next spark sql and so on. Finally, it creates a df which this function `func_test(spark,string1,string2)` returns.

Now, In the main class, I have to call this func_test and the two parameters string1 and string2 will be fetched from records of dataframe. So that, first func_test call generates query as `select * from dummy where CTRY='US' and CITY='LA'`. And the subsequent operations happen which results in df. Second call to func_test becomes `select * from dummy where CTRY='UK' and CITY='LN'`. Third call becomes `select * from dummy where CTRY='SN' and CITY='SN'` and so on.

Comment: I didn't get your question exactly, but I think you want to define new column by function on another 2 column value, Am I right?

Comment: No. I dont want to create a new column. I want to create a new dataframe ctry_df which does not have any relation with df. But ctry_df must have columns which are result of operation performed by func_test(a,b)

Comment: Do you want to create a new dataframe with the same schema?

Comment: The schema would be different of the new dataframe. If it is unclear, I can try to explain the question in a more detailed form

Comment: yes I think it is complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `first()` use `collect()` and iterate through the loop

```
collect_vals = df.select('CTRY','CITY').distinct().collect()
for row_col in collect_vals:
    func_test(spark, row_col['CTRY'],row_col['CITY'])
```

hope this helps !!

Comment: Why do we need distinct here? The combination of CTRY and CITY could be repeated also in some other row of the df.

Comment: Removed distinct and now it is able to working close to expected. Thanks

Comment: I assume you need to use single combination once. but if you don't want to de-duplicate than distinct is not required.

Comment: one input needed in continuation to this:- On first call of CTRY and CITY, a df(one row) is returned. On next call for next CTRY and CITY, next df(one more row) is returned. Is there a way to stack all these df one over the other and create a final df (or a temp table) with as many rows at the end?

Comment: You simply make a join with DF from where u r returning the filtered values. Join on the same key country and city.

Comment: 'from where u r returning the filtered values'. Could you pls elaborate this

Comment: where u r passing each value of 'CTRY','CITY' and filtering from the dataframe instead you can simply join `df` dataframe with other dataframe from which you are filtering values.